# How should I load and use global resources?

Tags: c++

I have a structure `EntityDog` that has a variable `sprite` that holds an image in it.

```
struct EntityDog {
    Sprite* sprite;
    Entity() {
        sprite = new Sprite("dog.png");
    }
    
    // some code....    
    
    void draw() {
        sprite->draw();
    }
};
```

This image will always be the same for all instances of the structure, but now I have to load it again every time I create an object, since I cannot think of any other good solutions.

I know I can pass a pointer to this image in the constructor, but that seems like a bad idea to me, because this image should always be the same.

And of course I can use global variables, but I think this is kind of bad form in c++

Comment: This is very opinionated.  There are many methods to load and store global resources depending on the platform and resource type.  There is no best practice.

Comment: One idea is to have a "registry" or database.  Give the registry ID and it returns a pointer to the sprite.  Let the registry manage the memory.

Comment: "I know I can pass a pointer to this image in the constructor, but that seems like a bad idea to me" why? That's literally what you want: to share the pointer.

Comment: @freakish: the next word of the sentence you quoted is "because" and that's followed by the answer to your question.

Comment: I recommend splitting the functionality.  Allocate the sprite inside an "initialize" method.  There are many containers and functions that may want to create the object without assigning the sprite (until necessary; on demand sprite assignment/loading).

Comment: @freakish Using a pointer isn't necessarily a bad solution, but I don't think it's a good solution either. I can't describe why, it just doesn't seem like the right way to do it. The fact that the sprite is an argument gives us the idea that it can be changed and that we can create two objects with different sprites. But we shouldn't

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Creating registry is a nice solution, but then how I will access this register? Should I make some kind of structure with static sprite members? And how will I access sprites? Using magic numbers for IDs is sure not a good idea

Comment: If you like, use `enum` for the IDs.  Use a `std::map` to associate the `enum` with a sprite pointer (this allows the sprites to be in read-only memory and you don't have to dynamically allocate them).  Or you could use a smart pointer (so that the sprite memory is deleted as necessary).

Comment: @Dirog I think you misunderstand things. Just because `EntityDog` accepts a pointer doesn't mean that it can be changed later. Actually, C++ already has a mechanism to prevent that: `const` keyword. Also, with smart pointers this becomes quite nice. Maybe, you want to preserve parameterless constructor, but that seems a weird approach. Don't you want to have a cache that returns `EntityDog&` when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a static member variable:

```
struct EntityDog {
    static Sprite* sprite = nullptr;
    Entity() {
        if (!sprite)
            sprite = new Sprite("dog.png");
    }
};
```

`static` means there's just one instance of the variable and it's shared by all instances of the class.

You might consider making `sprite` private, if it isn't meant to be directly accessed by code outside of `EntityDog`.